# Cheap EC Operations on Unsupported Curves

Tags: signature, cryptography, elliptic

I want to be able to verify signatures created by smart meters. Unfortunately, their signature algorithm doesn't use curve ALT_BN_128 but BrainpoolP256r1. I wrote [this verification algorithm](https://github.com/BlockInfinity/SmartMeterSignatureVerification/blob/e6e4d85d84ed7239bb269376e5fb65ab616ce196/Verify.sol) that requires an inversion, an addition of two curve points, and two scalar multiplications of curve points. The problem is especially the gas cost of the latter.

I wrote [a contract for these operations](https://github.com/BlockInfinity/EccOperations/blob/bf47c220c5ba1876c565c4bf1559300dd38c4613/EccOperations.sol) where the scalar multiplication is implemented via a simple double-and-add algorithm. Unfortunately, a scalar multiplication using this method costs between 84'000 and 19'000'000 gas. Originally, I didn't want to write my own contract for that but the only Solidity implementation I was able to find was `ECops.sol` by `orbs-network` (https://github.com/orbs-network/elliptic-curve-solidity/blob/master/ECops.sol). Scalar multiplication using this contract is much cheaper (about 623'000 gas), but then there's the minor disadvantage that the results are wrong.

Is there a better solidity implementation out there where I can just plug the right curve parameters in?

[I have asked this question on ethresear.ch](https://ethresear.ch/t/cheap-ec-operations-on-unsupported-curves/5904) but have yet to receive any answers.